# Как повторно получить значение с помощью cin?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вектор

Имеется задача:
Напишите программу, считывающую ряд чисел и записывающую их в **vector<int>** . После того как пользователь введет все числа, он может попытаться определить, сколько чисел он ввел, чтобы найти их сумму. Выведите ответ *N*, равный количеству элементов в векторе. Например:
"Пожалуйста, введите несколько чисел (для прекращения ввода введите клавишу < | >):"
**12 23 13 24 15**
     "Пожалуйста, введите количество чисел, которые хотите просуммировать:"
**3**
"Сумма первых **3** чисел: **12**, **23** и **13** равна **48**."

Я написал следующий код:

```
//#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please, input some numbers: ";
    int input = 0;
    vector<int> numbers;
    while (cin >> input) numbers.push_back(input);
    cout << "Please, input the number of values you want to sum: ";
    int number_of_values = 0;
    cin >> number_of_values;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<number_of_values; ++i)
        sum += numbers[i];
    cout << sum;
}
```

В данном коде не работает "*cin >> number_of_values;*", потому что, на сколько мне объяснили, в данный поток записывается **'\o'**(?) с предыдущего "*cin >> input*". Как можно изменить код, чтобы он работал? Во всех предыдущих заданиях не требовалось отдельно отслеживать символ "|", так как ввод завершается сам по себе из-за целочисленного типа переменной input. Не хотелось бы кардинально изменять код, потому что последовательно изучаю Страуструпа "Принципы и практика..." и некоторые темы еще не изучены.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос текст задачи текстом, а не изображением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо сбросить состояние ошибки потока `std::cin` и пропустить все ошибочные символы в буфере потока.

Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
std::cin.clear();

std::cin.ignore();
```

Это если вы хотите пропустить в буфере только один символ.

Либо

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cin.clear();

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
```

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это делается. Только вместо стандартного потока `std::cin` я для наглядности использую строковый поток `std::istringstream`. Вам в своей программе нужно просто заменить этот поток `is` на `std::cin`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is( " 12 23 13 24 15 | 3" );
    std::vector<int> v( ( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ) ), 
                        std::istream_iterator<int>() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    is.clear();
    is.ignore();

    int n = 0;

    is >> n;

    std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
12 23 13 24 15 
n = 3
```

Как видите, все работает так, как требуется.

Обратите внимание, что вы можете инициализировать вектор значениями из потока при объявлении самого вектора.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает, странно что это не рассматривалось в книге. Получается перед каждым cin нужны такие инструкции? Можно ли не вводить одно и тоже, а где-то один раз указать на сброс буфера? Или же код в моем случае не совсем верный и следует писать совсем по-другому?

Comment: @Side Если вы пытаетесь ввести число, а в буфере потока встретился нецифровой символ, то естественно состояние потока переходит в ошибочное. Вам надо его сбросить и пропустить ошибочный символ или все символы до символа новой строки.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отслеживать ввод символа |, полагаю что в примере входных данных должно быть что-то вроде "1 2 3 4 5 6 |". Cчитывать это можно например так

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::string input;
while ((std::cin >> input) && (input != "|"))
{
    numbers.push_back(std::stoi(input));
}
std::cout << "Please, input the number of values you want to sum:" << std::endl;
int int_input;
std::cin >> int_input;
//...........
```

Comment: А что произойдет в Вашей программе при ошибочном вводе (например, буква вместо числа в цикле наполнения вектора)?

Comment: До этого, в книге подразумевалось использовать любой символ для окончания ввода данных, может быть есть другое решение, без использования проверки символов?

Comment: 2avp - верно заметили, это моя привычка видеть в задании "гарантируется корректность входных данных", будет ексепшн. Ответ выше в данной ситуации лучше моего.